# log4j file wont created after I removed or the file has been archieve

Tags: java, log4j, tomcat9

I'm having a code running on Linux, and using Tomcat 9.
I'm using log4j as the to record the log. 
However, whenever I delete the file manually from the log folder :
/var/lib/tomcat9/logs , once I access the application, the log is not created.

Same goes when I deploy my code and accessing the application on 11.10.2019, today when I access the application again, log was not created. 
But program working-I saw new record added today.
FYI, on 11 Oct 2019, archieve file was created.

```
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat   615 Oct 11 17:12 Restful.log.gz
```

May I know is there any other setting or configuration that I missed out during my deployment.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/lib/tomcat9/logs/Restful.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: which version of `log4j` you are using 1 or 2?

Comment: log4j-1.2.15 @VishwaRatna